# Combine Two Regex Patterns

Tags: regex

I have these two regex patterns:

`^(?=.*?\b(?:Cow|Horse)\b)` for `I want to see Cow and Horse`

`(?!.*(Duck|Lamb).*).*$` for `I don't want to see Duck or Lamb`

I would like to combine them in to one expression. I've tried a few variations without success. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The result of the second pattern is certainly not what you hope since it matches `amb` at the end of the string. It probably needs to be anchored at the start of the string. You can write it in the same way than the first but with a negative lookahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
^(?=.*?\b(?:Cow|Horse)\b)(?!.*(Duck|Lamb)).*$
```

Comment: this one seems to be working well: [\s*.*]*vmxnet3\b(\s+.+)vmxnet3\b(\s.)